# Readjusting an exponential growth per year to per decade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given this function that models the growth of nation t years after a certain year:

$$P(x) = 51.53 + 1.022^t$$

So right from the start I can identify the initial population was 51.53 million people, and there is a yearly growth of 2.2%.

However, I have been asked to accomplish this task:

> What function displays the percent change in the population over the course of a decade as a constant or coefficient of the equation?

So for linear percent growth I could just say, if it grows 2.2% per year, then it will be 22% per decade. However, since it is exponential I wasn't sure on how to rearrange the percentage so it is accounted for 10 years.

I have considered plugging in values to get the percent change, so:

$$P(10) = 51.53 + 1.022^{10}$$
$$P(10) = 52.773108$$
So the percent change is
$$100(\frac{52.773 - 51.53}{51.53})$$
Percent change would be 0.02412, so about 2.4%. Therefore my function would be:
$$P(x) = 51.53 + (1.0241)^t$$

but I was told the answer actually is:

$$P(x) = 51.53 + (1 + 0.243)^{0.1t}$$

How do I maintain the same function but rearrange it to decades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

You have noted that $P(10)=51.53+1.022^{10}=51.53+1.2431..$ , so $P(t)$ [ not $P(x)$] is

$P(t)=51.53+(1.2431..)^{t/10}$

and, obviously, $P(1)=51.53+(1.2431..)^{1/10}=51.53+1.022$

Comment: I understand that in a decade the interest goes up to 1.2431 and the initial rate will always be 51.53. However, I don't understand why you divide time by 10?

Comment: Because we have the increment of $1.2341$ when $t=10$.